# Chrome Driver only supports Chrome Version 96 Error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have deleted and redownloaded 20+ different chrome and chrome drivers, trying to satisfy this error. I have spent 3/4 hours trying to figure this out. If someone could just redirect me a link of what I need to download in order to satisfy this error. My code works, but the drivers don't match well. Although the error is straightforward, I am struggling.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I have attempted to download chrome 96 but, that doesn't seem to solve it either, unless I have downloaded an incorrect one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Chrome 98 version you need 98.0.4758.102 version chromeDriver.
You can download it from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.102/)
I see you are using Windows OS, so you should download [chromedriver_win32.zip](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.102/chromedriver_win32.zip) from there.
For more information read [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error, I have no clue why.

Comment: I can't know since I can't see what's going on there on your computer, but I can guess you have multiple `chromedriver.exe` files of different versions so that Selenium sees the older version.  Try closing the IDE you are using, validate there is no older chromedriver files on your PC, especially inside your selenium project structure etc.

Comment: THANK YOU PROPHET, I realised I was changing the chrome driver on my PC, where my code was on a memory stick where the driver was supposed to be. Thank you for changing my train of thought :))